# Child Menu item not appearing in Admin System Menu - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, menu, submenu

I am trying to develop a **custom module** that must appear as a **sub menu item** in the `admin->system` menu.

I have been looking at a number of examples on Google and have been taking advice from this group and I think I am close to having my module working. The setup is running and the module is getting registered in the core_resource table and the table required to be created by this module is happening. At the moment the entry in admin->system is not getting created and after many hours of hunting and trying ideas suggested on various sites I am at a loss.

My module menu structure is as follows

```
app
   code
      local
         Steam
            Emarsys
               Block
               controllers
               etc
               Helper
               Model
               sql
```

In app/etc/modules I have Steam_Emarsys.xml and it contains

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Steam_Emarsys>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Steam_Emarsys>
</modules>

</config>
```

I assume this is working as the module is registered

In Emarsys/etc I have config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Steam_Emarsys>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Steam_Emarsys>
</modules>
<global>

    <blocks>
        <steam_emarsys_adminhtml>
           <class>Steam_Emarsys_Block_Adminhtml</class>
        </steam_emarsys_adminhtml>
    </blocks>

    <helpers>
        <steam_emarsys>
            <class>Steam_Emarsys_Helper</class>
        </steam_emarsys>
    </helpers>

    <models>
        <steam_emarsys>
            <class>Steam_Emarsys_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>steam_emarsys_resource</resourceModel>
        </steam_emarsys>
        <steam_emarsys_resource>
            <class>Steam_Emarsys_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <brand>
                    <table>steam_emarsys_brand</table>
                </brand>
            </entities>
        </steam_emarsys_resource>
    </models>

    <resources>
        <steam_emarsys_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Steam_Emarsys</module>
                <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </steam_emarsys_setup>
    </resources>
</global>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <steam_emarsys_admin>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
               <module>Steam_Emarsys_Adminhtml</module>
                <frontName>brand-directory-admin</frontName>
            </args>
        </steam_emarsys_admin>
    </routers>
</admin>

</config>
```

I also have adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<menu>
    <system>
        <children>
            <brand translate="title" module="steam_emarsys">
                <title>Manage Emarsys</title>
                <sort_order>120</sort_order>
                <action>steam_emarsys_admin/brand</action>
            </brand>
        </children>
    </system>
</menu>

<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <system>
                <children>
                    <brand translate="title" module="steam_emarsys">
                        <title>Manage Emarsys</title>
                    </brand>
                </children>
            </system>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

In controllers->AdminHtml I have BrandController.php and in there I have the ACL (isAllowed) funtionality

```
<?php
class Steam_Emarsys_Adminhtml_BrandController
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
public function indexAction()
{
    $brandBlock = $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('steam_emarsys_adminhtml/brand');

    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_addContent($brandBlock)
        ->renderLayout();
}

public function editAction()
{

    $brand = Mage::getModel('steam_emarsys/brand');
    if ($brandId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false)) {
        $brand->load($brandId);

        if ($brand->getId() < 1) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError(
                $this->__('Emarsys data no longer exists.')
            );
            return $this->_redirect(
                'steam_emarsys_admin/brand/index'
            );
        }
    }

    if ($postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost('brandData')) {
        try {
            $brand->addData($postData);
            $brand->save();

            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('Emarsys data has been saved.')
            );

            return $this->_redirect(
                'steam_emarsys_admin/brand/edit',
                array('id' => $brand->getId())
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }

    }

    Mage::register('current_brand', $brand);

    $brandEditBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
        'steam_emarsys_adminhtml/brand_edit'
    );

    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_addContent($brandEditBlock)
        ->renderLayout();
}

public function deleteAction()
{
    $brand = Mage::getModel('steam_emarsys/brand');

    if ($brandId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false)) {
        $brand->load($brandId);
    }

    if ($brand->getId() < 1) {
        $this->_getSession()->addError(
            $this->__('Emarsys data no longer exists.')
        );
        return $this->_redirect(
            'steam_emarsys_admin/brand/index'
        );
    }

    try {
        $brand->delete();

        $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
            $this->__('Emarsys data has been deleted.')
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
        $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
    }

    return $this->_redirect(
        'steam_emarsys_admin/brand/index'
    );
}

protected function _isAllowed()
{
    $actionName = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
    switch ($actionName) {
        case 'index':
        case 'edit':
        case 'delete':
        default:
            $adminSession = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
            $isAllowed = $adminSession
                ->isAllowed('steam_emarsys/brand');
            break;
    }

    return $isAllowed;
}
}
```

I am not seeing any log messages in exception.log, system.log or the apache logs

I am expecting to see the Manage Emarsys menu item at the bottom of the admin->system menu and the action for this menu item should be the Emarsys Block being rendered.

I would really appreciate any guidance or help as to what I am doing wrong. If anyone needs to see any other files I can post these